# ElasticSearch erroring out on script score that used to work fine

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I have several entity types indexed by ElasticSearch (using Elastica via the FOSElasticaBundle). All of them have an "importance" property, which is a stored integer.

I've been using a function score query that worked well to sort results based upon their importance.

In elastica, it looks something like this:

```
$nameQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$nameQuery->setFields(array('name'))
  ->setDefaultOperator('AND')
  ->setQuery($name);

//Create the script score that will modulate the score
$scriptScore = new \Elastica\Script("doc['importance'].value");

//Create the Function Score query that will bring it all together
$functionScoreQuery = new \Elastica\Query\FunctionScore();
$functionScoreQuery->setQuery($nameQuery);
$functionScoreQuery->addScriptScoreFunction($scriptScore);
$functionScoreQuery->setScoreMode('multiply');

$results = $this->find($functionScoreQuery);
```

This has been working fine for me UNTIL I indexed a new entity type recently. This new entity type also has an importance property which is also a stored integer. Now, when I use this same Function Score query on either the NEW entity OR the old entities (which used to work fine) I get a failure like the following:

```
Query Failed      [  
         Failed to execute main query
      ]
   ]   ; nested:GroovyScriptExecutionException   [  
      ElasticsearchException      [  
         java.lang.NumberFormatException:Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)
      ]      ; nested:UncheckedExecutionException      [  
         java.lang.NumberFormatException:Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)
      ]      ; nested:NumberFormatException      [  
         Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)
      ]      ;
   ]   ;
```

Some searching yields lots of thinking that params are global throughout ElasticSearch, and thus I may have a parameter on some other entity named "importance" which isn't an integer anywhere...but this isn't the case. The only "importance" parameters I have in the db are all identical, integers.

I've tried -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index/_optimize?max_num_segments=1' but this also did not appear to change a thing. I even tried, based upon another stack overflow discussion, changing the "integer" value to a "long" on one of my entity types and reindexing the entity, this also did nothing.

Anyone have any ideas? I've been pulling my hair out for days now.